# Creating a singleton container class for intrer-class messaging

Tags: python, classes, singleton, container

My question is for validation of my code (any loop holes / bugs) and guidance the best  methodology to implement for my requirement.

I am developing a Python application that will have many classes. We need to communicate in between each class - pass data. It would be very clumsy if across all classes I create a setter/getter method and refer them across different classes, hence I prefer to pass a container object in between all of them:

```
class One
  def __init__(self, container):

class Two
  def __init__(self, container):
```

Now obviously I want that this container object should be a Singleton object - only one instance to pass multiple data structures. Below is my code for same [class declaration for Container class]:

```
import abc

class Container(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    __data1 = 0
    __data2 = 0
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def dummy():
        raise NotImplementedError()
    def __init__(self):
        self.__data1 = 0
        self.__data2 = 1
    def SetData(self,value):
        self.__data1 = value
    def GetData(self):
        return self.__data1

class Singleton(Container):
    _instances = {}
    def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
        if class_ not in class_._instances:
                class_._instances[class_] = super(Singleton, class_).__new__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
        return class_._instances[class_]
    def dummy():
        pass
```

Now in my application, I would not be able to create an another separate instance of Container [abstract class] / Singleton class. So I can pass the object of Singleton like as mentioned below:

```
class One:
    def __init__(self, container)
        self.value = container.GetData()
        ................................
        container.SetData(9)
        Two(container)

class Two:
    def __init__(self, container)
        self.value = container.GetData()
        ................................
        container.SetData(19)
        ................................

class Three:
    def __init__(self, container)
        self.container = Singleton()
        ................................
        container.GetData() # will return value 19 only
        container.SetData(19)
        ................................



if __name__ == "__main__":
    container = Singleton()
    container.SetData(9)
    One(container)
```

Please comment on my approach and modifications required if any. This code will be pushed in production box - so I want to double check my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need a singleton. You are already passing around container references as parameters. So, if you only create one container in `__main__` and pass that to the class instances, they will all be accessing the same container.

Instead of calling `Singleton()` in `Three.__init__` you would simply do the usual thing:

```
class Three:
    def __init__(self, container)
        self.container = container
```